# Why Maven External JARs are not present in WAR file after build?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, pom.xml, parent-pom

I have included an external JAR and plugin in my pom.xml file using Maven, but when I to build and generate a WAR file, the generated WAR file does not contain the external JAR. How can I resolve this issue?

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>com.abbyy.FCEngine</groupId>
    <artifactId>FCEngine</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
<systemPath>${basedir}\src\lib\com.abbyy.FCEngine.jar</systemPath>
   </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
    <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement> 
 </build>
```

Comment: What do you mean by external jar? Share your pom so we can see the Maven configurations of the project.